# Why is there no shorthand for referring the object's members from its methods in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I did not understand the following sentence from Python tutorial:

> there are no shorthands for referencing the object's members from it's methods.The method function is declared with an explicit 1st argument representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call.

Does this mean, in every method of a class, its object is hidden along with the data members? Can this be explained with sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: I mean, the python interpreter in some way contains the  information about object in the memory.

Comment: That's not a lot clearer.  I mean, of course it does.  The running Python interpreter has to know everything about every object in the running program.

Comment: I thought the entire object is mixed up with the method in a class along with members. Its now clear to think in a way like, only "self" name is referred in the method and "self.var" is mapped to "var" of the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just referring to the fact that in an object's methods, the object itself is always the first argument (i.e., the "self" in `def method(self, arg1, arg2)`), and that you need to explicitly say that you want `self.var` in the method rather than just saying `var`.

For more background on why that decision was made, see https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls from the docs or http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html for some examples.